# How to do an index increment for my case?

Tags: python, numpy

I have to find the minimum for each column in a matrix, but there are two rules;

1. Each column will start from the "index+1" of the previous column, except for the first column
2. If one of the columns has exactly the index equal to the total number of rows of the matrix, then the rest indices for all the columns will be equal to the number of rows

As an example;

```
[[ "-1".  -11.    0.    8.    1. ]
 [  2.    1.    0.    5.    1. ]
 [  4.    1.   -2.    6.    7. ]
 [  8.    3.    1.    3.    0. ]
 [  5.    "0".    1.    0.    8. ]
 [  9.    3.   "-1".   -1.    6.5]
 [  5.    3.    2.    5.    3. ]
 [ 10.    3.    7.    "1".   "-1". ]]
```

The indices are inside quotations, [0,4,5,7,7]

Another example;

```
[[ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 2.  1.  0.  5.  1.]
 [-4. -1.  2.  6.  7.]
 ['-5'  3.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 5.  '0'.  1.  0.  8.]
 [ 5.  3. '-1'. -1.  0.]
 [ 5.  3.  1.  '1'.  0.]
 [ 5.  3.  1.  1.  0.]]
```

The indices here are [3,4,5,6,7]

I tried to do the following, but I am having errors. Could you please tell me how to do so?

```
def lst_min(matrix, columnindex, minIndex):
    if minIndex == matrix.shape[0]:
        return matrix.shape[0]
    else:
        return np.argmin(matrix[minIndex:, columnindex]) + minIndex
currentMinIndex = 0
lst = []
for i in range(a.shape[1]):
    w = lst_min(matrix=a, columnindex=i, minIndex=currentMinIndex)
    if w > a.shape[0]:
        w = a.shape[0]
    lst.append(w)
    if w == 0:
        c = 1
        currentMinIndex = w + c
    if currentMinIndex > a.shape[0]:
        currentMinIndex = a.shape[0]
```

Comment: What's the error you got?

Comment: @SCKU
The values I am getting for the first matrix using the given code are these: [0, 4, 2, 5, 7], the correct values are [0,4,5,7,7]
and for the second matrix, [3, 2, 5, 5, 3] which is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code use lst.append(w) with some strange logic...

You use `lst_min` to find minimum index but you simply `return matrix.shape[0]` when `currentMinIndex = 0` (`minIndex == matrix.shape[0]`) at start.

FIY,

```
# post source code next time if you can,
# it will be really helpful to others to run your question easily
# and focus on the main problem quickly.
a = np.array(
    [[ -1,  -11,    0,    8,    1. ],
     [  2,    1,    0,    5,    1. ],
     [  4,    1,   -2,    6,    7. ],
     [  8,    3,    1,    3,    0. ],
     [  5,    0,    1,    0,    8. ],
     [  9,    3,   -1,   -1,    6.5],
     [  5,    3,    2,    5,    3. ],
     [ 10,    3,    7,    1,   -1. ]]
    )

b = np.array(
    [[ 1,  1,  0,  0,  1],
     [ 2,  1,  0,  5,  1],
     [-4, -1,  2,  6,  7],
     [-5,  3,  1,  1,  0],
     [ 5,  0,  1,  0,  8],
     [ 5,  3, -1, -1,  0],
     [ 5,  3,  1,  1,  0],
     [ 5,  3,  1,  1,  0]]
    )

lst = []
start_idx = 0
for vec in a.T: # forloop column-wise
    if start_idx >= vec.shape[0]-1: # index compare shape, should -1
        lst.append(vec.shape[0]-1) # put the last index
    else: # find minimum index
        min_idx = np.argmin(vec[start_idx:]) # slice it 
        start_idx += min_idx # add back the true index
        lst.append(start_idx) # append to result
        start_idx += 1 # next column, use index + 1 (your rule 1)
        if start_idx >= vec.shape[0]-1: # but if it is larger or equal, fit it back for next column use
            start_idx = vec.shape[0]-1
```

The results should be:

```
>>>lst
[0, 4, 5, 7, 7]
# code change to b.T
>>>lst
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working on my case. 
Best Regards